# Why does htaccess rewriteRule not work and returns 404 not found

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to make simple image cacher

Idea is to request `http://example.com/folder/00filename` which is translated by `.htaccess` to `http://example.com/folder/00/00filename`.

If it does not exist, then call `.php` script.

PS: There is also `?url=` part `http://example.com/folder/00filename?url=http://s2.example.com/imagetocache.png` which is needed by `index.php`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /imagecache/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/imagecache/$1/$2/$2$3 !-f #works
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.{2})(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L] #works

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/imagecache/$1/$2/$2$3 -f #works
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.{2})(.*)$ dump.php [QSD,L] #works (if uncommented)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.{2})(.*)$ $1/$2/$2$3 [QSD,L] #does not work - returns 404 not found
```

Also, why these do not work? It's like `ENV:REWRITEBASE` is empty for RewriteCond but not for RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{ENV:REWRITEBASE}/$1/$2/$2$3 -f
RewriteCond %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}$1/$2/$2$3 -f
RewriteCond /$1/$2/$2$3 -f
RewriteCond $1/$2/$2$3 -f
```

Comment: is there any rule/code to populate `ENV:REWRITEBASE`?

Comment: No there isn't. Its automatcally populated from `RewriteBase` as far as I know, isn't it?

Comment: But `RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.{2})(.*)$ $1/$2/$2$3 [QSD,L]` should have worked after checking for `RewriteCond` above it

Comment: It works and matches, but produces 404. Still I think i found problem.

Comment: Well if it produces 404 then it doesn't work

Comment: "`ENV:REWRITEBASE` .... Its automatcally populated from RewriteBase as far as I know, isn't it?" - No, it's not.